# Biztalk bug? XSD chokes when using hyphen or period in element name when global (referenced)

Tags: .net, xsd, biztalk

Here is some code of an XSD that is VALID in XML Spy but chokes in Biztalk on the referenced elements using a period or hyphen.  Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong, or confirm this is a bug or a "feature?"  Does anyone have a workaround?  I have googled and searched high and low for anomolies in XSD/XML validation in .NET (and BizTalk) and have not seen anything (anyone with similar question or problem.)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2012 rel. 2 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by ZiggyDude (PA DPW-BIS) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="DotNetRestrictions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="Valid">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Embedded-Hyphen"/>
                            <xs:element name="Embedded.Period"/>
                            <xs:element name="Embedded_Underscore"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Invalid">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="Embedded-Hyphen"/>
                            <xs:element ref="Embedded.Period"/>
                            <xs:element ref="Embedded_Underscore"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Embedded.Period"/>
    <xs:element name="Embedded-Hyphen"/>
    <xs:element name="Embedded_Underscore"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Notice the embedded underscores do NOT fail in .NET.  Have gotten this to work by changing all periods and hyphens to underscores, but the sending agency will NOT provide the XML or XSD in an "underscore" format.  The files go out to too many places with periods and hyphens.  We either need to 1) configure this right so it works if possible, 2) fix BizTalk and .NET (heh.heh.heh) or 3) transform these XML documents on the fly to replace the periods and hyphens prior to processing.

Thoughts? and please confirm/dispute my theory that BizTalk/.NET chokes on these chars when elements are called as a reference.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the symptom of BizTalk "choking" is that you're getting an error along these lines:

> Node "Embedded.Period" - Specify a valid .NET type name for this root
>   node

Then you can fix that by selecting the problematic nodes in the BizTalk schema editor and modifying their Rootnode TypeName property. Swap out the periods or hyphens for underscores - this only impacts the .NET type that gets generated, not the XML representation - and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the error (choking!). We can do what you suggest (and yes the XSD will validate), however, the XML that will come in to validate a/g the XSD comes from another agency that we have no control over. We will have to convert the incoming XML on the fly to replace the hyphens and periods as well. We have already identified that yes, this will work, but would rather have a bug-free Biztalk. From what I can see this has been an issue for several years and yet has not been fixed. Perhaps it cannot be. Looking for some other workaround if possible...

Comment: The answer above suggests that if you follow the prescribed steps, you don't need to change the incoming Xml. This solution concerns BizTalk only and doesn't affect the Agents. Sounds like a good workaround to me - one i've used in the past, too! Are we missing something?

Comment: OK.  This Newby is humbly thankful!!  I was not familiar with the "Rootnode TypeName property" in BizTalk .net apps as most of what I do is in plain VB .NET.  teepeeboy, your gracious comment suggetsed I did not follow to the letter (without calling me an idiot!) and so I went and was able to understand his solution and it worked!  So thank you BOTH for responding, bcause it took both of you to let your knowledge seep into this brain!!  AWESOME.

Comment: I don't see a way to mark my original question as answered by this response...  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! To mark this answer as accepted, click the button underneath the up/down buttons to the left of this answer. This page on the FAQ provides some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Done!  Thanks!!  I have another question coming out presently under XML...  Hope you will see it!

Answer (score 0):

By replacing the offending characters in the "Rootnode TypeName property" to an underscore, the XSD validates on its own and is able to accept the incoming XML with offending characters in the element name.

The code was

```
<xsd:element name="Embedded-Hyphen" type="xsd:anyType"/>
<xsd:element name="Embedded_Underscore" type="xsd:anyType"/>
<xsd:element name="Embedded.Period" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Adds this to each element:

```
<xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:appinfo>
      <fieldInfo rootTypeName="Embedded_Period" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"/>
    </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
```

And now looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Embedded-Hyphen" type="xsd:anyType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <recordInfo rootTypeName="Embedded_Hyphen" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Embedded_Underscore" type="xsd:anyType"/>
<xsd:element name="Embedded.Period" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <fieldInfo rootTypeName="Embedded_Period" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

THANK YOU GUYS!